# @JsonAlias on @ModelAttribute POJO not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Jackson in my Spring Boot application.

I want to convert request parameters to POJO.

But when I use `@ModelAttribute` with `@JsonAlias`, it doesn't work.

**Request POJO**

```
@Data
public RequestPojo {
    @JsonAlias( "FOO_SNAKE" ) // Not working
    private String fooCamelAlias;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public void getFoo( @ModelAttribute RequestPojo requestPojo ) {
    ...
}
```

**Request:**

```
(1) http://localhost?FOO_SNAKE=Foo_snake
(2) http://localhost?fooCamelAlias=Foo_snake
```

`fooCamelAlias` is null when I request with `(1)`.
But `(2)` works.

Comment: I've tried it with simple spring boot project with only ```Application.java``` and ```Controller.java```. No other settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonAlias` will not work with `@ModelAttribute` because `@ModelAttribute` is used for binding data for request param (in key value pairs). If you want to do JSON mapping then better to use `@RequestBody`